# Is there any way to prevent celery from doing apply_async if the task with provided task_id already exists?

Tags: celery, gevent, worker, celery-task, greenlets

I have been expecting problems when celery has started 2 tasks with the same id in parallel.

We can prevent this by checking if the celery already has task with the specified id and do not send the task, however, the way is not a really beautiful one.

Are there any ideas on how to make it in a beauty manner?

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in the [Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time) section of the Celery documentation.